# How much Bitcoin will I mine right now with hardware X?

Tags: mining-profitability, mining-hardware

Say I have a given piece of hardware (CPU/GPU). Where can I find out how much Bitcoin will I mine per day?

Comment: Bitcoin Mining Profitability Calculator: http://bitcoinX.com/profit

Comment: [BitCoin Mining Hardware profitability](http://bitcoineval.com/hardware.php). By the way [due to the rising hashrate of the bitcoin network caused by the introduction of ASICs to the market, CPU/GPU mining Bitcoins has become impracticable](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Non-specialized_hardware_comparison), you'll spent more money in energy than you gain in Bitcoin.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Go to http://bitminter.com/test and click the "test start" button. If you have Java installed the miner should launch. Click "engine start" on your GPU(s) to start mining and the GUI will show how many bitcoins per day you will make (on average).

Note that you are actively mining in a pool without getting paid. This test page launches a version of the miner which is only meant to be used for a short time for testing.

**Update for 2015**: CPU and GPU mining are both long dead. When you buy ASIC mining hardware you will know its hashrate before you buy. Don't buy if you don't. Google "bitcoin mining calculator", input your hashrate, and it will tell you how much you can earn right now, on average. Note that the difficulty will change in the future so your earnings will not stay the same. Also note that with most pools actual earnings vary with luck. Finally, avoid the typical newbie mistake of confusing TH/s and GH/s. 1 TH/s = 1000 GH/s.

Comment: 2018, GPU for btc is dead but not for other currency.

Answer (score 31):

There is a list here that is kept relatively up to date with the possible hashrate of various CPUs and GPUs

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_hardware_comparison

Once you know the number of hashes you can generate, you can use an online mining calculator and calculate the numbers of bitcoins you can mine per day (on average) and the current price of those bitcoins in other currencies.

http://tpbitcalc.appspot.com/

It is worth pointing out that when most people talk about "mining" bitcoins these days, they are talking about pooled mining. Depending on the fees of your pool you can make anywhere from 2%-10% less than expected. If you mine by yourself, the bitcoin you are expected to make has a high degree of variance.

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Pooled_mining

Comment: These days when you say. do you mean 2018 or 2011?

Answer (score 28):

D = Difficulty
H = MHash/s
C = Reward (currently 12.5 BTC)

> 24 / (D * 2^32 / (H * 10^6) / 60 / 60) * C = BTC/day

Comment: Take note that the last figure (50) in this formula is the block reward, which at some point will halve to 25 and continue halving until it reaches zero, at which point mining will be subsidized only by transaction fees, which this formula also ignores. It's not unreasonable to ignore them for the time, since they're a very tiny fraction of mining income, but still :)

Comment: Can you explain or reference what the 2^32 number is from and how its calculated?

Comment: A difficulty of D requires on average 2^32*D hashes to solve. In fact, that's not entirely accurate. The exact number is 2^48/65535*D.

Comment: @Pieter Wuille...So is his formula correct, because PEMDAS matters? I am trying to build my own calculator on my web page, for my own use, where ALL inputs are required. Many of these online calculators do not include, or allow input of variable items that are important.

Comment: What is PEMDAS?

Comment: Operation order; parentheses, exponents, multiply, divide, add, subtract

Comment: @Pieter Wuille...PEMDAS is operation order; Parentheses, Exponents, Multiplication, Division, Addition, Subtraction. I believe the correct formula is ...(DaysInMonth * Hashrate * BlockReward * SecsInDay) / (Difficulty * Exponent)  ..to get the monthly mined coin rate

Comment: The formula is correct, but one of the constants is slightly off (by about 0.0015%).

Comment: this doesn't make sense .../60/60 means that the two 60 cancel out.... and so you end up with 24/(D*2^32/(H*10^6))*C

Comment: @Naz No it does not.

Comment: Where does the `24` come from?

Answer (score 11):

If:

```
D is the current difficulty
H is your hash rate in Mhash/s
B is block reward in BTC
```

Then you can expect to earn:

```
  (H*B/D) * (60*60*24 * 65535 * 10^6 / 2^48)
= (H*B/D) * (5.662224e15 / 2^48)              BTC per day (1)
```

or roughly:

```
  (H*B/D) * 20.11626                          BTC per day (2)
```

The current block reward B is a little over 12.5 BTC if you take transaction fees into account. (The transaction fees vary block by block; the core reward halves periodically, e.g. to 6.25 in mid-2020.)

(1) is exactly correct

(2) is an approximation, correct to 7 significant digits

[This answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/135/659) is slightly off due to assuming 65535 == 65536.

Comment: So what's the values of `D`, `H`, and `B`? There's a load of multiplications but none of them show `12.5` so it's impossible to disassemble this.

Answer (score 4):

Yet another [bitcoin mining profitability calculator](http://blockchained.com/profit) - detailed and including a decline factor to compensate for mining hardware advancement (I am the author).

Answer (score 2):

You should consult [this wiki entry](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_hardware_comparison) to know how many hashes per second can you generate with your hardware. Afterwards, just input the value into a [bitcoin mining calculator](http://www.alloscomp.com/bitcoin/calculator.php) and you will have an estimation of your payout ratio.

Please note that this calculator does not take difficulty into account so your earned value is likely to change over time. There are [other calculators](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=26751.0) that try to predict the evolution of the difficulty, but they are not very accurate. Right now, difficulty depends on too many factors to be correctly predicted for a period longer than a couple of months.

Answer (score 1):

I was confused by the profitability calculators I saw because I find it hard to get a feeling for how the difficulty influences my yield and also for where I can expect the difficulty to go, since it's such an abstract value.

So I now use what to me is more intuitive: there's a (more or less) fixed number of 3,600 BTC gained from mining each day, until the block reward halves in 2017. Those coins can be viewed as being shared by the whole network proportionally to the computing power of each player.

So, let's assume a network power of 360 Thash/s, which seems not far away as I write this, and makes for easy calculation, then for every Ghash/s that your equipment brings to the table, you get 0.01 BTC per day.

If you're solo mining, this is overly simplified, but the general direction of solo mining is that your actual yield will only on average match the theoretical one, so if you're much much smaller than the network (likely), then your variance gets so high that it becomes a lot like a lottery.

Answer (score 1):

NiceHash has a nice calculator that will give you [expected return on crypto mining, based on hardware and electricity price](https://www.nicehash.com/profitability-calculator#)

Answer (score -2):

If you are interested in how your profitability will change as the network hashrate grows this calculator is the best IMO.

http://bitcoininsight.com/2013/04/05/bitcoin-mining-profitability-calculator/

Although you will have to make some guesses about how the network will grow, it should be more accurate than just a plain guess as to what the difficulty will be in X months time.

Comment: This page 404's for me. Do you have a link that doesn't?

Comment: I found the correct link and submitted an edit to this answer: http://bitcoininsight.com/2013/04/05/bitcoin-mining-profitability-calculator/