# Exactly how does one calculate how many BTC they will get a certain hashrate?

Tags: mining-profitability, money-supply, hash

I am curious on how many estimated BTC I will earn at any hash rate since, I don't really think I'm really earning any BTC at 600 Mhash/s.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How much Bitcoin will I mine right now with hardware X?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-much-bitcoin-will-i-mine-right-now-with-hardware-x)

Comment: Similar, but I wouldn't consider them duplicates. In this one you know your hashrate, in the other one you just know what hardware you have. They should certainly be linked though.

Answer (score 7):

The answer of D.H. assumes the hashrate of the network never changes between difficulty jumps. But it can in fact evolve quite a bit, so it can be inaccurate sometimes. Your proportion in the network may change but, until the difficulty adjusts, this will *not* change your rewards.

Your average reward will be :

[image]

So, in your case, with 600 MH/s and a time period of 1 day, the result is, in average, **0.3394412542813765 BTC a day** (with current difficulty).

Explanations: the first term is the average reward per difficulty-1 share, and a difficulty-1 share is found in average every 2^32 hashes.

Now, if you're going to be pooled mining, adjust the 50 in the formula to take fees into account (use 48.5 for example for a 3% fee). Same goes when blocks start generating 25 BTC only.

Comment: If you're going for that degree of accuracy, it should be noted that difficulty 1 does in fact not correspond to 2^32 hashes, but to 2^48/65535 (4295032833 instead of 4294967296).

Answer (score 4):

You can see an estimation of the total hashrate [here](http://bitcoinwatch.com/). At this point 12.85 Terahash/s. So your share of that would be 600/12850000 = 0,00004 = 0,004%.

50BTC / 10 minutes are awarded to miners, that is 7200 BTC /day.

0,00004 * 7200 = 0.34

So, roughly 0.34 BTC/day if my calculations are correct.

---

Also, [here is a list of calculators](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Profitability_Calculator) that can be used.

- http://bitcoinx.com/profit/
- http://0x10.org/sandbox/bitcalc/
- http://bitcoin.web-share.nl/

The last one seems very easy to use, simply input your hashrate and press "calculate".

Comment: That partially answers my question, but is there a calculator that tells the hash rate, and considers difficulty changes along with the  price?

Comment: Added some info on calculators.