# What hashing speed does my hardware have?

Tags: hashpower, terminology, mining-hardware

I'm checking [this page](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_hardware_comparison) to know what hashing speed my hardware has. But there's no explanation about the acronyms.

For my Core 2 Quad Q9650, what's the expected hashing speed?

Comment: The speed is in the Mhash/s column

Comment: Very related question: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-much-bitcoin-will-i-mine-right-now-with-hardware-x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Wiki:Mining hardware comparison](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_hardware_comparison): Core 2 Quad Q9650 - 18.67 Mhash/s . With current price and difficulty factor there is no point in using CPU for mining because the profit won't cover the cost of hardware or electricity. For example with current difficulty it will take you 8 years on average to uncover block and earn 50 BTC or 1/2 BTC a month if mining from a pool.

Today everyone uses video cards to mine e.g. ATI 5970 has about 800 Mhash/s, which is about 43 times faster then your CPU. Bitcoin network adjusts difficulty factor so bitcoin production rate would stay roughly the same, about 50 bitcoins per 10 minutes. CPU mining can do only a small part of total workload therefore you would receive on average a very small part of the reward.

Answer (score 3):

The table in the linked page says it's  18.67 MHash/s. That's very low, mining with a CPU is pointless.

Comment: To explain why it's pointless... when you mine with a CPU you pay more in electricity than it would cost to buy the same amount of a bitcoin that you are producing.