# How much are accepted shares on GUIMiner worth?

Tags: mining-profitability, hashpower

I have just started Bitcoin mining and am using GUI Miner. I have an AMD 7870 OC edition that is mining for me. Currently i'm getting 380 mhash/s, is this good? Also how many of the accepted shares are worth 1BTC?

Answer (score 1):

> I have just started Bitcoin mining and am using GUI Miner. I have an AMD 7870 OC edition that is mining for me.

Welcome to mining. It's a blast.

> Currently i'm getting 380 mhash/s, is this good?

For Bitcoin, it's unlikely to be profitable unless your electricity cost is very low. See [How much Bitcoin will I mine right now with hardware X?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-much-bitcoin-will-i-mine-right-now-with-hardware-x) for more information.

> Also how many of the accepted shares are worth 1BTC?

None. It is unlikely that you will see 1 BTC total mining on that card during its lifetime. See the above link for why.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try out a calculator first. It is usually easiest to calculate your mining rate by comparing your hashing rate with the current difficulty rate, and then just remove the 1% fee from the pool.

http://www.bitcoinx.com/profit/

Comment: Or, put in another way, you're probably spending in power more that you're earning. Bitcoin is currently dominated by ASICs. I suggest moving to ASIC-resistant altcoins.

Comment: kaoD means Scrypt coins - use Coinwarz.com and mine anything with Scrypt.  BTC mining utilizing GPUs has been Dead since July  2013