# Can I do mining with a normal PC?

Tags: cpu-mining

Can I do mining with a normal PC in my house?

I will setup Linux ([Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29)) for mining. It will be open 24/7. I don't have too many expectations. Maybe 0.1 in one week?

Comment: Related: [How much Bitcoin will I mine right now with hardware X?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-much-bitcoin-will-i-mine-right-now-with-hardware-x)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Can i do mining with a normal PC?

Yes, you can.

> I don't have too many expectations. Maybe 0,1 in one week?

No, not possible. You will effectively compete against all computational resources on Earth, that are now cracking this nut. If I can estimate, a humble home PC will produce around 1 - 100 MH/s, based on [CPU or GPU mining stats](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_hardware_comparison). This range covers different CPUs and single-GPU computers. You can compare hash rate with the profit estimate using [this calculator](http://www.bitcoinx.com/profit/). Based on the hash-rate, your electricity bill will much out-weight any profit from mining.

To achieve a 0,1 BTC/week you'd have to invest in a pretty expensive, power-hungry ASIC box that can produce tens of GH/sec, subject to ever-increasing complexity.

Comment: Actually, to be honest, a normal PC even is capable these days to make a only share, so it is possible you cannot mining at all.

Answer (score 2):

To get 0.1BTC in one week with current difficulty levels you need to have at least 3.000 MHash/sec ASICminer.

A regular GPU will provide just 50 ~ 60 MHashes so it will take quite a bit longer to achieve 0.1BTC.

My recommendation is to get one of these ASIC miners to get a better performance:
http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_odkw=asicminer+block+erupter&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=p2045573.m570.l1313.TR5.TRC1.A0.Xasicminer+usb+block+erupter&_nkw=asicminer+usb+block+erupter&_sacat=0

Comment: Could you show your work? Assuming "3.000" means three thousand MHash/sec, I'm getting that this would earn you an average of 0.01 bitcoins per week or so, not 0.1.