# Does this mean it's mining?

Tags: ubuntu, bfgminer, miner-configuration, cpu-mining, stratum

I'm using my personal computer and trying to mine bitcoins.

I'm rather new to this and was wondering if I did everything alright. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: No, it means that no devices were found.

Comment: @NickODell So, it only works with these usb devices, is that correct?

Comment: It depends on what's enabled when compiling bfgminer. Where'd you get it?

Comment: @NickODell http://askubuntu.com/a/388976/371965

Comment: It may help if you provide more information about what you want to achieve. E.g. what device are you trying to use? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Murch I'm using my personal computer and trying to mine bitcoins.

Answer (score 3):

1. You are using an ancient version of `bfgminer`
2. CPU mining was disabled by default even in `bfgminer 3.10.0`, your gpu doesn't seem to get detected
3. You're about 4 years late for CPU mining and 3 years late for GPU mining: Even if you get `bfgminer` to run, your PC will not be powerful enough to even find shares that would be accepted by a pool. See e.g. [Can I do mining with a normal PC?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/20045/5406)

Comment: So, that is that. Thank you for your information.

Comment: In recent versions of bfgminer, GPU mining is also disabled for the same reason. Not sure if that applies to OP's version or if their card is simply unsupported.

Comment: GPU was still enabled then. From the [bfgminer 3.10.0 release notes](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=168174.0): Features: [...] OpenCL GPUs, such as AMD Radeons [...]