# Calculating the mining profitability of Novacoin

Tags: alternatives, mining-profitability

I've been researching altcoins and keep coming across some staggering figures. I think it's just too early to do math, but if I were to farm novacoins for example [calculator here](http://www.coinwarz.com/calculators/novacoin-mining-calculator) and I have pretty much no cost (0 power and 0 hardware), my rig can run 500-600 Mhash/s (aka 500,000-600,000khash/s since that's what the calc uses), lets ignore difficulty increase. The calculator says I can make ~$100 PER DAY. This can't be right, can someone figure out what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Closely related: [How much Bitcoin will I mine right now with hardware X?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/118/5406)

Comment: Well it sort of is related but with the difficulty right now it's not logical. Im mostly trying to figure out if I flubbed my math, am crazy, or should quit my day job.

Comment: NVC uses Scrypt as it's hashing algorithm, like LTC. If that 500-600 MH/s figure is for Bitcoin, your speed will be significantly lower for NVC.

Comment: I edited it for you. I should note that my hardware is still rated for about 500 Mh/s according to the litecoin wiki.

Comment: There is nothing in the Litecoin wiki list https://litecoin.info/mining_hardware_comparison that does 500 Mhash/sec. The entries in that table are in Khash/sec and the largest entry is 1500. I bet your machine actually does 500 Khash/sec meaning you will earn about 10 cents per day.

Comment: Then, I guess we could delete this, as it is too localized and unlikely to help anyone else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the hardware and do not pay for your power consumption, then it follows that you would always have 100% profit. If you pay for your own power consumption, you need to be aware that performing mining calculations all day will significantly increase your computer's power usage in comparison to being idle.

I haven't checked the validity of the calculator, but you can calculate your potential mining yield from your mining power and the current difficulty.

Check out [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/135/5406) on [How much Bitcoin will I mine right now with hardware X?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/118/5406) for a formula.

Then, it depends on whether it is actually possible to sell the coins that you gained (whether there is a market for it), and whether the above information is acurate, otherwise, it might well be possible to make a good amount of money mining altcoins.

Comment: I'm just finding it hard to believe that I can make $100 per day with my 270x. I'm at work and forgot to set up teamviewer this morning, but I'll try my hand at mining altcoins tomorrow/later tonight.