# Seeing no Hash per second on any pool

Tags: mining-pools, p2pool, guiminer

I'm a newbie to bitcoin and having a hard time trying to take part of a pool. I subscribed to various ones, including :
eu.p2pool.cloud or give-me-coins

And mining from windows with the following soft:
guiminer.org

For instance, in order to mine on eu.p2pool.cloud, I'm entering the following parameters in the gui:

Host: eu.p2pool.cloud
Port: 9332
username: 1NMNeA1ViusfvmX9mwNe2UiGUcNHwSaWL4 (this is my payout address)
password: xxx

Selecting my GPU, and having ~20MHashs/s displayed in the GUI. My fan is working a lot so I'm guessing calculations are really happening.

Letting it run for about 20 mins...

And when I'm logging in http://eu.p2pool.cloud/#/user I'm seeing 0 everywhere, bitcoin count, Hash/s etc.

I understand I am very very unlikely to get a bitcoin with my machine in such a short amount of time, but why I'm seeing 0 even on Hash/s ?

Same happens for give-me-coins.

Am I missing something ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Gpu mining still an option?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/41125/is-gpu-mining-still-an-option)

Comment: @PhilBrun: Current ASICs are at least a factor of 1000 times more energy efficient and generate in the range of 10 THash/s. You cannot expect to ever gain any revenue with your GPU. Also see: [In the ASIC-age, is it worth starting mining Bitcoin at home?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/41276/5406)

Comment: Thanks Murch, I'm running on my GPU for test purposes only, for now, but was surprised to see zeros everywhere on my account, even in Hash/s, hence my question

Comment: Unfortunately GPU is now too slow even for testing.

Comment: Note that unless you compiled your own mining software, most software has GPU mining disabled by default. You have to compile a custom version to even enable GPU mining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pool calculates your hash performance from the number of shares that your miner produces. With so little hashing power, it's likely that your miner did not generate a single share, so to the pool it's indistinguishable from doing no work at all.

Comment: Many thanks. Do you know how much time nowadays it takes on average on a pool like p2pool, to get a single share at 20MHash/s ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know - with low probabilities, it's hard to tell. It's somewhat like playing in a lottery, even if your chances are significantly better than the chance of mining a full block as a solo miner. To experience the thrill of mining, you might want to look for altcoins which can still be reasonably mined using a GPU.

Comment: Some hand-waving napkin math for you Phil - pool vardiffs target a share rate on the order of 1 per second, but will have a minimum which we won't know off-hand.. 20 MH is 1/50,000th of 1 TH, or about 1/250,000 times the power of a mid-range ASIC, meaning if the minimum share diff is close to that 1/s target for a mid-range ASIC, you can expect to wait about 3 days before you see an accepted share, and  with a bit of bad luck, you could wait as long as a month.