# Bitcoin hardware

Tags: miner-configuration, mining-profitability

I want to start mining but I am not sure about my calculations. Is it worth to mine with 4 nvidia gtx titan X without paying for electricity? I calculated it with a bitcoin calculator and the money are incredibly low. I did something wrong for sure. Titan X has 1980 hash rate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Gpu mining still an option?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/41125/5406), [In the ASIC-age, is it worth starting mining Bitcoin at home?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/41276/5406), [How much Bitcoin will I mine right now with hardware X?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/118/5406),…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, you didn't do anything wrong. You're about 4 years late, the days of gpu mining are over.

Comment: I was going to mine at work. My dreams are over.

Comment: @Dexxrey well at least now you get to keep your job.

Comment: I researched the bitcoin mining hardware its unworthy even with free electricity. Antminer s9 2400$ 1-3 you will need 1-3 years to return your investment at this state. Also something unexpected might happen I consider mining in 2016 unworthy.