# Mining with only 1 GPU

Tags: gpu-mining, gpu

I have a GTX Ttan and plan on getting a GTX 1060. I want to only mine with the 1060. How would I do that. Im using sgminer v5.3.1

Comment: If you are talking about mining Bitcoin, you should really read http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/41125/is-gpu-mining-still-an-option and http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/41276/in-the-asic-age-is-it-worth-starting-mining-bitcoin-at-home before investing any time or money into this.

Answer (score 1):

Mining almost any crypto-currency, including Ethereum, with just one GPU is not recommended if you are wanting to actually make profit. This segment of miners are viewed as enthusiast with the goal of just contributing to the security of the network. If you do not have these goals, it is advised to avoid mining at large.

Mining requires large amounts of electricity, GPUS, and multiple rigs (aka mining farms). Most residential home-miners will generate some amounts but will never generate enough to even break even, resulting in a negative ROI (return on investment).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do that? Just to learn about how mining works?

Are you interested in mining Bitcoin? According to my understanding mining for Bitcoin with a GPU is perhaps not the best allocation of resources, but maybe it's a good choice for Ethereum or some alt coin.

Comment: No not btc. Im talking about ETH.