# When do I get paid when mining with eligius?

Tags: client, gpu-mining, mac, eligius

So, i'm trying out mining with a mac and i'm not asking whether mining is possible, my question is is it actually even possible to make a minimal amount of bitcoins. I hear people saying that mining with bitcoin has now become "competitive" and I wonder if that means if we are fighting over who completes a block? I'm using eligius because they are one of the few pools that let people mine with gpu. When will I get paid? Do I need to keep mining for a few hours? Any help will be appreciated. thx. BTW: here is a my console log, is this correct?

```
[2017-05-24 13:58:39] API running in IP access mode on port 4052

 [2017-05-24 13:58:39] API running in IP access mode on port 4052
 [2017-05-24 13:58:39] Selecting poclbm kernel
 [2017-05-24 13:58:39] Error -30: Clearing output buffer for goffset test kernel (clEnqueueWriteBuffer)

 [2017-05-24 13:58:39] Error -30: Clearing output buffer for goffset test kernel (clEnqueueWriteBuffer)
 [2017-05-24 13:58:39] Initialising kernel poclbm.cl without bitalign, 1 vectors and worksize 256

20s:15.38 avg:39.71 u: 0.00 Mh/s | A:0 R:0+0(none) HW:0/none
20s:24.76 avg:39.65 u: 0.00 Mh/s | A:0 R:0+0(none) HW:0/none
20s:29.70 avg:38.93 u: 0.00 Mh/s | A:0 R:0+0(none) HW:0/none
20s:33.60 avg:39.14 u: 0.00 Mh/s | A:0 R:0+0(none) HW:0/none
20s:35.92 avg:39.23 u: 0.00 Mh/s | A:0 R:0+0(none) HW:0/none
 [2017-05-24 14:00:29] New best share: 2
20s:36.92 avg:39.11 u:71.49 Mh/s | A:0 R:0+0(none) HW:0/none
20s:38.17 avg:39.26 u:91.92 Mh/s | A:0 R:0+0(none) HW:0/none
20s:38.54 avg:39.24 u:80.43 Mh/s | A:0 R:0+0(none) HW:0/none
20s:39.22 avg:39.36 u:71.49 Mh/s | A:0 R:0+0(none) HW:0/none
20s:39.15 avg:39.32 u:64.34 Mh/s | A:0 R:0+0(none) HW:0/none
20s:39.01 avg:39.28 u:58.49 Mh/s | A:0 R:0+0(none) HW:0/none
 [2017-05-24 14:02:33] New best share: 2
20s:39.55 avg:39.37 u:71.49 Mh/s | A:0 R:0+0(none) HW:0/none
20s:39.51 avg:39.38 u:82.48 Mh/s | A:0 R:0+0(none) HW:0/none
20s:38.38 avg:39.18 u:76.60 Mh/s | A:0 R:0+0(none) HW:0/none
20s:35.81 avg:38.68 u:71.49 Mh/s | A:0 R:0+0(none) HW:0/none
20s:36.02 avg:38.54 u:67.02 Mh/s | A:0 R:0+0(none) HW:0/none
20s:36.92 avg:38.53 u:63.08 Mh/s | A:0 R:0+0(none) HW:0/none
20s:37.48 avg:38.52 u:59.57 Mh/s | A:0 R:0+0(none) HW:0/none
```

Comment: Bitcoin mining with a GPU is absolutely impractical, and has been for awhile.   Modern hardware uses [ASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application-specific_integrated_circuit) and is much faster than GPU mining.  See also: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/41125/is-gpu-mining-still-an-option?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You will never get paid, because your miner is too slow to provide useful work to the mining pool.