# Good Bitcoin Mining Software?

Tags: mining-software

Does anyone know of any of the best Bitcoin Mining Software? I have been looking for mining software for a while, but I can't seem to find any. I'm using Windows 8 if that helps.

Comment: Unless you're just doing this to learn, its not worth it. We're long past the point where mining on a normal computer is anything but a losing venture.

Comment: relevant: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-much-bitcoin-will-i-mine-right-now-with-hardware-x

Comment: Modern bitcoin ASIC machines have a tiny built-in computer pre-installed with the necessary software. You do not need to download any software to mine.

Comment: relevant: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/62355/bitcoin-calculator-based-on-my-machine

Comment: what is "best" in your definition. Mine would be, the one which is most secure and heats best the room, without providing any revenues. Thats what you could achieve with your windows system. btw: questions which are opinion based doesn't make sense in the forum, you may want to read the help topics before posting.

Answer (score 4):

The only two that I know of are [cgminer](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/CGMiner) and [bfgminer](http://bfgminer.org/). Unless you have specialized mining equipment (read: ASICs) or mining on testnet, mining is not going to be a good idea.