# Bitcoin calculator based on my machine

Tags: mining-hardware, mining-profitability, mining-reward

I tried to find an online tool that would allow me to calculate how many BTC (or portions of it) I might be able to mine with my computer, but I couldn't find an answer that is exhaustive.

Is there any such tool?

Comment: Your computer is worthless for Bitcoin mining.   All BTC mining is done with custom built ASIC rigs which are billions, if not trillions of times faster than the best home PC.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. How do one knows it? 
Imagine I'd like to calculate how many computers equals to the one I have I'll need to mine a bitcoin; how do I calculate that?

Comment: @Adriano Increasing the number of computers won't change anything because you are multiplying by zero. Computers are currently useless for bitcoin mining because the power they use costs more than the bitcoins they mine are worth -- many, many times more.

Comment: I might not have issues with power supply. I just want to understand, given my hardware, how long it will take to mine a bitcoin.
I am not concerned about the energy bill :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the comments were pretty clear about, "don't even try this", you seem insistent.

Mining Power is measured in Gh/s, or Giga-Hashes per second, which means how many ***Billion*** hashes can a computer try every second.

The mainstream ASIC processor, AntMiner S9, can do about 13 Th/s (13 Terra-hashes, or 13,000 Gh/s).

A good graphics card GPU can do about 1 Gh/s.

So you would need on the order of 13,000 graphics cards to come close to a single ASIC processor.

Since the S9 has a breakeven point around 1 year, it would take your PCs about 13,000 years to make enough money to buy a single S9, and the PCs would be far more expensive upfront, and use far more electricity along the way.

Bluntly put, if you really really focused with PC mining, you'd be extremely lucky to make about $3 a year.

---

References:

[Is Gpu mining still an option?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/41125/is-gpu-mining-still-an-option)

https://bitmain-alliance.com/product/antminer-s9/?gclid=Cj0KCQiAuZXQBRDKARIsAMwpUeTtoNrXLyaRXqeHuVyaoEj4jeGUrx4zyJGeVYQpTUcvHllr41MKvb8aAj1iEALw_wcB

https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/calculator/btc?HashingPower=4730&HashingUnit=GH%2Fs&PowerConsumption=1293&CostPerkWh=0.12

https://99bitcoins.com/2016-bitcoin-mining-hardware-comparison/