# setup bitcoin miner on older hardware

Tags: mining-hardware, mining-setup

Hey my name is Philip and i would like to setup a bitcoin miner.

I am working on a school with loads of older pc's that i thought to be fun to set up for mining bitcoins, and i'm asking if it would be possible.

It is a lot of older hp pre built office pc's with no gpu's.

I want to do it for the experience of setting it up and don't expect to make any profit at all.

Comment: related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/41276/5406

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if it would be possible.

no. this would be wasting energy for heating the room

[How much Bitcoin will I mine right now with hardware X?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-much-bitcoin-will-i-mine-right-now-with-hardware-x)