# How does difficulty impact profitability? what is the formula?

Tags: mining-profitability, difficulty, antminer

I have an Antminer S9 ASIC miner , and I have visited [this](https://antminerprofitability.com/antminer-s9-profitability/) , but I want to know how difficulty may impact my profitability in the future. I would also like to estimate break even costs.

Comment: The higher the difficulty, the more work it takes to find a block. As difficulty increases, your profit will decrease

Comment: related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/118/5406

Answer (score 1):

[image]

<sup>Source: http://bitcoin.sipa.be/speed-lin.png</sup>

The difficulty growth has been slowing down over the years, but in the last year it still has about quintupled.

[image]

<sup>Source: http://bitcoin.sipa.be/growth-10k.png</sup>

The general formula for calculating profitability is elaborated on [How much Bitcoin will I mine right now with hardware X?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/118/5406).