# What is the minimum hash rate power should I have to get rewarded in btc.com?

Tags: mining-profitability

I just want to know how much minimum hash rate power should someone have to receive reward in btc.com or other pools?

Answer (score 0):

There is no definable minimum, because the expected reward for having *x amount of hashpower* is constantly changing. As other miners add or remove hashpower from the network, the effective 'minimum' would be expected to change. The answer to your question will also depend on the fees and policies of btc.com, so it does not fit the scope of questions for this site very well.

See also: [How much Bitcoin will I mine right now with hardware X?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-much-bitcoin-will-i-mine-right-now-with-hardware-x)