# How can i mine bitcoins to direct wallet using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I heard that we can mine bitcoins using javascript direct to the wallet?

How can I create Program, script or application which direct mines to the wallet & I even search online but did not get any appropriate answer so, I am here for a suggestion or advice.

Comment: I think your heard a wrong information, I think you can not mine bitcoins with Javascript or application on a normal computer or server

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo, Please correct me.

Comment: I think you should be starting to this https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/blob/develop/ch10.asciidoc is a basic guide and you can jump inside the book if you don't know am some else from bitcoin. I think from your question, that you are new in Bitcoin and I'm sorry is impossible now mining a bitcoin with normal PC, you arrived 11 years later.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How much Bitcoin will I mine right now with hardware X?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-much-bitcoin-will-i-mine-right-now-with-hardware-x)

Comment: See [A brief history of Bitcoin Mining hardware](https://thenextweb.com/hardfork/2018/02/02/a-brief-history-of-bitcoin-mining-hardware/)