# Mining Pool hub support cpu miner?

Tags: bitcoind, mining-pools, client, mining-theory

I have a simple/old CPU (like dual-core/Quad-Core) with unlimited electricity and all the other stuff.
I would like to run 10 PCs with **CPU** mining.
It's better to mine solo or the join mining pool hub?
I know the profit of the mining will be very very low (I don't care :D)

**Thanks for the help, Roee!**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How much Bitcoin will I mine right now with hardware X?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-much-bitcoin-will-i-mine-right-now-with-hardware-x). You are competing in a series of round the world races using a child's pedal car while other competitors are all using hypersonic intercontinental ballistic missiles. The prize money for your pedal car won't be low, it will be zero. No race teams will accept help from pedal car owners.

Comment: With solo mining, realistically you won't mine a single cent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are about 10 generations of mining hardware too late to mine bitcoin with CPUs, mining pool or not.

2009: Bitcoin launched with CPU mining. I've been told that some people mined 50 or 100 bitcoins per day with an old laptop.

2010: GPU (graphics card) mining made CPU mining hard, so mining pools were invented. This way people could still mine with CPUs.

2011: GPUs had to get on mining pools, and CPUs were next to useless. Some hardcore CPU miners kept going but earned little. Gaming PCs made a good profit.

2011-2012: The first specialized bitcoin mining hardware based on FPGA chips. FPGAs gave GPUs a hard time. Some GPU miners kept going, but in 2012 earnings were slim.

2013: The earliest ASIC miners shipped to customers in january. ASIC mining completely destroyed CPUs, GPUs and FPGAs for mining.

Since 2013 there have been many generations of ASIC miners, each making the older ones obsolete.