Is there a guide or system to determine mining-profitability?
I would like to ask this question because I want to introduce in the mining and I am looking for models that I can determine if a win money or not(objective function maximize profit for example, I put the energy consumption, and more variables) .
Is there some guide or academic literature about that?
Thank you

Have you looked at other questions tagged with mining-profitability?

https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-much-bitcoin-will-i-mine-right-now-with-hardware-x
